# I have a requirement to filter records (Date) less than a next month using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for vba code to filter all the dates less than end of next month and then count the values of visible cells

I have been using below code but not able to get the result

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim crit As String

crit = "<" & DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    .Range("A:CZ").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=crit, Operator:=xlAnd
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't end of next month be `Month(Now())+2`?

Comment: Thanks xshen and Notus_ Panda. I have just started learning an understanding the code. Actually I have used severals options by modifying month and date but none of them worked for me. Even applying +2 is giving addition of 2 days in filter. Just to re-clarify for e.g. if I am filtering out data in Sep, then data should filter all the past dates till Oct end.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the current month, and `Now() + 2` only adds two days. If you create another variable say `FutureDate` and
use `DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 2, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)))` you will get the last day of the next month. Using this method, you will always get the last day of the next month. Then you can use <= to include this date, or < to exclude the date. `Range("A:CV").CurrentRegion.Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count` will give you the visible rows, and the -1 accounts for the heading.

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim crit As String
Dim FutureDate As Date
Dim VisibleRowCount As Long

FutureDate = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 2, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)))

crit = "<=" & FutureDate

Sheets(1).Range("A:CV").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=crit, Operator:=xlAnd

VisibleRowCount = Range("A:CV").CurrentRegion.Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bob. The modification I am now trying to paste the value of visible cells in next sheet e.g sheet2. Could you have a workaround for this??

Comment: This should be easy. If you select the entire region, it should only copy and paste the visible cells.

Comment: Thank you once again Bob, sorry but would like to correct my query. I need the count of visible cells in another sheet

Comment: Just add "Sheets()." in front of your "Range().". Specfy the sheet you would like to look at in the parentheses. Also, if the above was useful you should accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks Bob, but it's not working for me. Below is the code I have modified and sheets I am working on. Sheet 8 and Master report 

crit = "<=" & FutureDate

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Report").Range("A:CV").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=crit, Operator:=xlAnd.      .
Range("A:CZ").Autofilter field = 59, Criteria1 := "In progress", Operator:=xlAnd.
VisibleRowCount = Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A:CV").CurrentRegion.Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1.       I am filtering columns in Master report and need count of visible rows in sheet 8

Comment: I ran a test in the Immediate window, and it is producing numbers for me. It is hard to say with the small samples I am seeing.
?Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A:CV").CurrentRegion.Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
 2 
 9 
 0

Comment: Thank you so much Bob it worked. !!! Thanks once again for all your support.